# How to upload video to youtube from my app?

Tags: android, post, retrofit, youtube-data-api

**In my app :** I wayt to pick a video from gallery and upload it to

youtube as unlisted with title, description.I got token.But idk how to

send post request.Any advice or sample code please ?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code:

```
// Sample java code for videos.insert

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();
        String mime_type = "video/*";
        String media_filename = "sample_video.flv";
        HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("part", "snippet,status");


        Video video = new Video();
        VideoSnippet snippet = new VideoSnippet();
        snippet.set("categoryId", "22");
        snippet.set("description", "Description of uploaded video.");
        snippet.set("title", "Test video upload");
        VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
        status.set("privacyStatus", "private");

        video.setSnippet(snippet);
        video.setStatus(status);

        InputStreamContent mediaContent = new InputStreamContent(mime_type,
        ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream(media_filename));
        YouTube.Videos.Insert videosInsertRequest = youtube.videos().insert(parameters.get("part").toString(), video, mediaContent);
        MediaHttpUploader uploader = videosInsertRequest.getMediaHttpUploader();

        Video response = videosInsertRequest.execute();
        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

More info: [YouTube Developer Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)